# Output of Hive String Function to be replaced by the values in Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a Table like below sample set.

```
 ColA
 AAAA
 BBBB
 CCCC
```

I used following query to get the output.

```
SELECT LPAD (ColA,5,'0')FROM TableName;
```

I get following output.

```
  ColA
  0AAAA
  0BBBB
  0CCCC
```

But I want to replace the value in table with the output values. Is it Possible?
If yes, some help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you column "colA" is String, you can definitely store the values as in output. Only in  Integer it truncates preceding zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert overwrite table from itself:

```
insert overwrite table TableName
SELECT LPAD (ColA,5,'0') as ColA,
       ColB,
       ...
       ColN
  FROM TableName;
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but in this set i have given a single column, but my data has multiple columns, and i have to apply change in only 1 column so when i try to use overwrite. it throws following exception: Table insclause-0 has 5 columns, but query has 1 columns.

Comment: @Shubzumt Of course you should add all columns from from original table, they should be in the same order, same number of columns.

Comment: @Shubzumt See updated answer. Column order in select statement should be the same

Comment: thanks man! It totally resolved my problem. But just curious what if number of columns are very large like 200-500 columns, then?

Comment: Yeah it worked! What i am asking is cant i provide some index in query rather writing all column names?

Comment: @Shubzumt No, that is not possible unfortunately. * is possible if you do not need to transform columns and the structure is the same